# How to handle Typescript dependency in a monorepo?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, monorepo, npm-workspaces

I have a monorepo using npm workspaces, the structure is as follows:

```
web
  -package.json

api
  -package.json

common
  -package.json

package.json
```

I have some utility functions and types in "common" package which I use in my web and api packages. Do I need to install typescript as a dev dependency in each package or installing it at the root folder is enough (my current setup) what are the cons/pros? One more question if I have some utility that is in the api package and want to use it in the web package do I need to move it to "common" package and import from there or I can directly import from the api package? Thanks

Comment: A mono-repo is basically a collection of packages, but I would say you still want to treat them as separate, all the mono-repos should be doing for you is making sure all local packages are linked locally.   If you extracted a single package from your repo, it should be able to stand on it's own.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice way to think about packages in a mono-repo.